# Nginx перестал работать [Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Перестал запускаться Nginx, выдается вот такой Log

```
root@main-server:~# service nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-09-02 09:38:14 UTC; 5min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 25717 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
  Process: 26217 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 26207 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25512 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 02 09:38:12 main-server systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 02 09:38:12 main-server nginx[26217]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 02 09:38:12 main-server nginx[26217]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 02 09:38:13 main-server nginx[26217]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 02 09:38:13 main-server nginx[26217]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 02 09:38:14 main-server nginx[26217]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 02 09:38:14 main-server nginx[26217]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Sep 02 09:38:14 main-server systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 02 09:38:14 main-server systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 02 09:38:14 main-server systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

Вот так настроен config

```
server {
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

Ранее все работало, но после обновления (а может и нет) стали возникать такие ошибки.

Сервер предоставлен DigitalOcean.

Comment: Покажите вывод команды `netstat -tanp`.

Comment: @de_frag, думаю, что так лучше: https://pastebin.com/WnYXBqbe
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                25731/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                550/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                919/sshd
tcp        0    464 104.131.96.54:22        176.59.19.11:49777      ESTABLISHED           5140/sshd: root@pts
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN                919/sshd

Comment: Лучше вывод прикреплять к самому вопросу (редактировать вопрос), а не в комментарий. Что касается самого вывода команды, то присутствует следующее: `25731/nginx: master`. Этот процесс управляется через `service nginx stop/start`? Если нет, то возможно его придется прибить через `kiil -9 25731`, например.